# Reading string value from registry key

Tags: c++, registry, windows-7-x64, visual-studio-2008-sp1

My simplified code:

```
HKEY hKey;

if(someCondition)
    lRes = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);
else
    lRes = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARW\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);

if(lRes == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    std::wstring strKeyValue;
    lRes = GetStringRegKey(hKey, L"valueName", strKeyValue, L"bad");
    if(lRes == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
         //doSomething
    }
}
```

Both `RegOpenKeyExW()` return `ERROR_SUCCESS` but in one case (reading from `Wow6432Node`) the `GetStringRegKey()` returns `ERROR_SUCCESS` and initializes the `strKeyValue` and in other case it returns `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`. All paths and value names are right. The entries were added to the registry manually.

What is the problem? Is the any credentials issue? Thanks!

Comment: You hae a typo at line: `lRes = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARW\\Wow6432Node\\`. It should be "SOFTWARE". 
Also, you don't need to include the `\\Wow6432Node\\` when opening the registry key. Windows OS will do that for you. You just need to know about it when you go LOOK in the registry yourself using the RegEdit.exe tool.

Answer (score 0):

Note: The original question for this was what is the difference between using HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, and why does using one work and the other not. This is the answer posted to that question.

Taken From Microsoft Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724475(v=vs.85).aspx

> The HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT (HKCR) key contains file name extension
>   associations and COM class registration information such as ProgIDs,
>   CLSIDs, and IIDs. It is primarily intended for compatibility with the
>   registry in 16-bit Windows.
>
> Class registration and file name extension information is stored under
>   both the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE and HKEY_CURRENT_USER keys. The
>   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes key contains default settings that
>   can apply to all users on the local computer. The
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes key contains settings that apply
>   only to the interactive user. The HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT key provides a
>   view of the registry that merges the information from these two
>   sources. HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT also provides this merged view for
>   applications designed for previous versions of Windows.

So the difference is: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` will present a unified view of the registry for previous version of Windows, and merges the default user settings with the current user settings. It is primarily for use for reading the interactive user's settings. It shouldn't be used for storing values, only for reading, as can be found in the link provided, and it actually maps into the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER' hive.

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER` is the "true" registry path, so all interaction with the registry that requires write access should go through it instead, due to security reasons. Which branch to take depends on whether you are updating just the user's settings in the registry, or all user settings in the registry.

Comment: How does it explains the `FILE_NOT_FOUND` received when reading from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`?

Comment: The entry you asked for doesn't exist or you cannot access it with your current creditionals. You should check what you are asking for, and check the registry to make sure the path is correct to the entry you are trying to reach. If you are running a 32 bit app on a 64 bit OS, such as Windows 7, you will find that the actual registry key is not where you think as they insert a "Wow6432Node" after the "SOFTWARE" key.

Comment: Just as a follow up--- the OS will take care of 32 bit apps running under "WoW64" (and therefore under mapping their registry calls into the Wow6432Node), but if you go look into the registry yourself, you need to understand that the extra hive is there.

Comment: The entry I'm trying to read is an entry I've added manually to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` path.

Comment: Actually I'm reading values successfully from the `Wow6432Node` path. What is the issue of the credentials? The path is: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run`

Comment: The process accessing the registry key must have the necessary privilages granted to it. If an admin creates a registry key, a simple user sometimes cannot read that created registry key. it is best to have the user create their own registry keys (via the software) so they will have the necessary privilages to read it back.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26061/discussion-between-sanich-and-starpilot)